# Did Stack Exchange change the upload host for images?

Tags: bug, images

I was reviewing the edit queue and realized that I can't see images any more, Did Stack Overflow change the upload service provider for images?

Because I'm from Iran maybe the new host has some IP address limitation access from countries (and my country is in the forbidden country list probably)...

Comment: Wouldn't it be related to the HTTPS switch? Can you normally access the images when they're served with HTTPS?

Comment: @Tunaki , I'm not sure , but when I use VPN ( for changing IP) I can see images.

Comment: Does Iran block https connections? From [this document](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#iran) it states a license is required for encryption, but I'm not sure whether or not it's strictly enforced.

Comment: @Rob , No I don't think problem is from country , I think image host bans IP addresses from Iran.